# Using multiple regexp parameter for Angular UI Router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using AnglarJs and Angular UI Router for my project.
I'm using parameters for my route such as:

```
url: '/content/:categoryId/:categoryType'
```

But I got problem when using url:

```
url: '/content/detail/:contentId'
```

It seem Angular UI Router can not recognize the difference of these 2.
Then I decide to use regexp parameter for all of them

```
url: '/content/{categoryId:int}/{categoryType:int}'
url: '/content/detail/{contentId:int}'
```

The second url is ok but Angular UI Router can not recognize the first one when I using ui-sref:

```
<a ui-sref="firstUrl({categoryId: 1, categoryType: 2})">Anchor</a>
```

Was Angular UI router support just one regexp parameter?

Comment: Usually it's a good idea to start with the 'static' ones and the dynamic urls later to avoid conflicts. Try putting the 'detail' one first.

Comment: Thank you very much! By rearrange order of routes, I've solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is in the way how UI-Router is finding/resolving state for `url`. It uses:

- the order of state defintion
- first matching is used

And that is in fact the issue, because first url pattern:

```
url: '/content/{categoryId:int}/{categoryType:int}'
```

is absolutely suitable for the url provided for this one

```
url: '/content/detail/{contentId:int}'
```

Solution in these cases is relatively simple. Change the order of state definitions. The more precise should go first, the more dynamic second